# ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_positional_args' from 'sklearn.utils.validation' to import imblearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imblearn

I am installing imbalanced-learn. it has successfully installed but on importing i am getting this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_deprecate_positional_args' from 'sklearn.utils.validation' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py)
```

how to resolve this please help

Answer (score 0):

Due to some mismatched dependencies versions, it appears that an error has been received.

**Check the requirements for imbalanced-learn package from here:**
[requirements](https://pypi.org/project/imbalanced-learn/)